# Error importing CountVectorizer from sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, pycharm

When I try the following import statement

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.1\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .dict_vectorizer import DictVectorizer
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.1\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\dict_vectorizer.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ..utils import check_array, tosequence
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.1\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.1\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\class_weight.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import in1d
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.1\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 318, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.1\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    from .isolve import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.1\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.1\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import _iterative
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.1\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm currently using Windows 8 64-bit, PyCharm 4.5.1 with Python 2.7.1 (64-bit) and have already installed scikit-learn 0.16.1 and it's dependencies (Numpy 1.9.2 and 0.15.1 as listed in [Scikit Installation guide](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/install.html)):

- Python (>= 2.6 or >= 3.3)
- NumPy (>= 1.6.1)
- SciPy (>= 0.9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using Anaconda? I think that's one of the more popular scipy distributions, and it's pretty stable. Also make sure you use `pip` or another package manager to install your packages.